# nAnt script needs to get parent directory

Tags: nant

I am writing a nAnt script and need to get the parent directory.  I have used:

```
<property name="perforceWS" value="${project::get-base-directory()}"/>
```

this returns the current directory.  How can I get the property to be the parent's directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming You mean the parent directory of the project directory (the directory where the NAnt build script is located) this is the answer:

```
<property
  name="perforceWS"
  value="${directory::get-parent-directory(project::get-base-directory())}"/>
```